# Dynamic Sampling Rate for Audio Recording Android

Tags: android, audio

Is it possible to change the sampling rate while recording an Audio in Android using `AudioRecord` or `MediaRecorder`?

Both of these class requires to initialize first the sampling rates before recording an Audio, But I was wondering if I can change the sampling rate, let's say 8000 to 16000 and vis-a-vis, in the middle of recording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would you expect to happen when you change the sampling rate once it is recording?  Setting the rate directly is not supported by [AudioRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html), so that is a definite no.

Setting the rate directly with [MediaRecorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) is allowed, but is expected to be done before starting the recording.  I would not expect all, if any, implementations of the Android OS to handle this.